# Style: color doesn't work in option

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I read many questions like this and I found many solutions but none of them is working for me...

What I want? I want a dropdown menu with the default option black, but the others red, so I can see when I change something. I could use javascript onchange on  but I prefer act on  using in-line CSS.

To make it simple we start with this code `html`:

```
  <p>Title:
    <select id='myid'>
      <option value="Myoption1" selected>Option 1</option>
      <option value="Myoption2"><span style="color: 'red';">Option 2</span></option>
      <option value="Myoption3" style="color: 'red';">Option 3</option>
    </select>
  </p>
```

Neither work: the text stay black.

In truth my dropdown is generated by javascript so the code is more complicated but I think the problem is here.

Edit this doesn't work either (with or without';'):

```
  <p>Title:
    <select id='myid'>
      <option value="Myoption1" selected>Option 1</option>
      <option value="Myoption2" style="color:#FFF000;">Option 2</option>
      <option value="Myoption3" style="color:red;">Option 3</option>
    </select>
  </p>
```

Comment: Your third option is the proper way to approach this, however you should not have single quotes around `'red'`. Just do `style="color: red;"` on the `<option>` itself. Commenting instead of answering, as I don't think the solution to this question should merit rep.

Comment: Before to ask I made many try and neither of them worked. I try without quotes too but doesn't work for me. I think yours snippet for you work (of course) but not for me so the problem has to be somewhere else

Answer (score 2):

Remove the quotes

```html
<p>Title:
    <select id='myid'>
      <option value="Myoption1" selected>Option 1</option>
      <option value="Myoption2" style="color: red;">Option 2</option>
      <option value="Myoption3" style="color: red;">Option 3</option>
    </select>
  </p>
```

Although, a better practice is to use CSS for this

```css
option:not(:first-child) {
   color: red;
}
```

```html
<p>Title:
  <select id='myid'>
    <option value="Myoption1" selected>Option 1</option>
    <option value="Myoption2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="Myoption3">Option 3</option>
  </select>
</p>
```

This looks a lot cleaner, and provides a separation of concerns.

Comment: I tried that but doesn't work so probabily is firefox? Your snippet doesn't work for me

Comment: I hope it is possible using in-line CSS because I generate my code with Javascript

Comment: For me doesn't work neither of your snippet. I change option but the text is always black

Answer (score 0):

I can see that in your style format has some wrong value which is inverted coma or some thing like that. I think your codes should be like this `style="color:red;"`

Answer (score 0):

you must do two things

- remove **`<span>`** tag from **`<option>`** tag,it won't work

> ie,you need to replace `<option><span></span></option>` with
>   `<option><option>`

- remove single quotes(')from your color property it also won't work.

> ie, you need to replace color:'red' with color:red

```css
option{
  color:red;
  }
```

```html
<p>Title:
    <select id='myid'>
      <option value="Myoption1" selected>Option 1</option>
      <option value="Myoption2">Option 2</option>
      <option value="Myoption3">Option 3</option>
    </select>
  </p>
```

Comment: @fabio then explain what are the current problems  you are facing,i will help you to fix it

Comment: Just the text is always black

Comment: @fabio which browser you are using and the version?do you need every menu item in red color or only the 2nd and 3rd?

Comment: I'm using firefox 50.1.0. I need red all of them but not the selected one

Comment: I mean the one selected by default, like I said in my first post: <option selected>

Comment: @fabio ok check now,you need to avoid the inline style because which will override the stylesheet propeties